# Best design for emailing groups of Users that are collaborating on a Case

Tags: email, visual-workflow, case, notification, design

We're using Cases, but long-story-short, we're not really using Service Cloud licenses. We have a heavily restricted form of Service Cloud licenses.

We need to be able to have teams of people across our organisation work on a Case together. We are building a custom "Case Roles" object to track which people/teams a Case is shared with for collaboration purposes (I will mention why we are not using Case Teams later on), and we are using Flow to manage the sharing based on those Case Roles. The sharing is working perfectly. Now we need to figure out **notifications for these Case Roles**.

**Our Requirement:** We want to be able to set up email notifications which get sent to the Case Owner and ALSO all related Case Roles. A Case Role can be for an individual OR all individuals with a particular **role in the role hierarchy**. We have 250+ roles in our system.

*For example:* if a Case is closed, we want to notify the Case Owner and also all related People/Roles that have been added as Case_Role__c records.

**So... What's the best way to notify all these different people?**

Here's my initial thinking:

1. **Chatter** isn't really an option right now for various reasons, one of which is that it would require creating some sort of automation to create & sync 1 x Chatter Group for every Role in our system (Our Roles represent the various teams of Users who would work on Cases).
2. **Email Alerts + Flow** will be a terrible admin burden because we would need to create and manage 1 x email alert for every Role per each type of email notification. If we just have 4 types of email notifications, we would have to create and manage more than 1000 email alerts. We would also need to use pretty gnarly flow logic to determine which is the correct email alert to send to each Case Role.
3. **Lightning Email Templates sent via Flow** would be a little annoying because we would have to query every user in a role (there could be multiple roles added as Case Roles), concatenate all their emails, and email them all individually. I'd have to use Apex or the [UnofficialSF Send Better Email package](https://unofficialsf.com/send-better-email-flow-action/) to be able to send an email to > 5 recipients.

So far Option 3 looks like the best. ARE THERE ANY OTHER DESIGN APPROACHES THAT I SHOULD BE CONSIDERING FOR THIS REQUIREMENT?

**Why we don't use Case Teams:**

We manage users via Okta. There is frequent movement of Users leaving the organisation or switching roles. We would need to create 250+ Case Teams to mirror each of the Roles we have created in our Role Hierarchy, and then ensure that we keep them in sync with those Roles over time. Case Team objects also have limitations around what automation you can build on them. So as far as I can tell, using Case Teams rather than a custom Case Role object doesn't get us any closer to what we are trying to achieve.